# Magento2: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Vault\Api\Data\PaymentTokenInterfaceFactory in Cart and Checkout

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, fatal-error, http-error-500

Recently, I upload my **Magento 2** site to production server, and everything looks fine, except by Cart and Checkout. When I enter to these, the server throw me a HTTP ERROR 500, and the page keep blank.

In Php Error Log, is displayed this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Vault\Api\Data\PaymentTokenInterfaceFactory in vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:93
Stack trace:
#0 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Vault\\A...', Array)
#1 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(130): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Vault\\A...')
#2 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(67): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\\Vault\\A...')
#3 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Paypal\\...', Array)
in vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93
```

The other sections display well, only cart and checkout have this problem. Additional, this occurs only in Production. In my developer server, all is fine.

Comment: hmm got that same error in a fresh magento2.2.0 installation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first, please, provide Magento version of your application.

Starting Magento >= 2.1.3 version the `Magento\Vault\Api\Data\PaymentTokenInterfaceFactory` is no more autogenerated factory (the autogenerated code is "private" and can be changed in any patch release).

Instead of using `PaymentTokenInterfaceFactory` you should specify concrete factory for payment token. Magento provides two factories out of the box:

- `\Magento\Vault\Model\AccountPaymentTokenFactory` - for payment methods which work with payment profiles like PayPal, Authorize.net, CyberSource
- `\Magento\Vault\Model\CreditCardTokenFactory` - for payment methods, which tokenize credit card details, like Braintree.

More details about both factories and their purposes you can find in [Magento payments documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/vault/payment-token.html).

Magento Vault does not provide default preference for `PaymentTokenInterfaceFactory` interface because only payment integration 
knows about the type of token.

**UPD**: Starting from 2.2.0 release the `\Magento\Vault\Api\Data\PaymentTokenInterfaceFactory` has been deprecated and `\Magento\Vault\Api\Data\PaymentTokenFactoryInterface` should be used instead. The [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/payments-integrations/vault/payment-token.html) has been updated as well.

Comment: Well, I have the Magento 2.1.1 version, but... Yout comment throw me to the right path to notice my error. I will comment what I do, but I will consider your comment as answer, because in this case I think that it will be the "normal" solution to others. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try:

- Make sure the PHP module intl is installed;
- rm var/generation/*
- rm var/di/*
- rm var/cache/*

  bin/magento setup:upgrade

  bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. intl is installed, and I tried remove generation, di, cache, and after upgrade and compile, but the error persists.

Comment: Hi, You can check your di.xml file if you did not leave something broken in a comment or close the <preference>

Answer (score 0):

I feel a little embarrassing right know. Thanks to **joni jones** comment about **Magento 2.1.3** and **PaymentTokenInterfaceFactory** , I could see that, in fact, that was the source of my problem. But, the strange is that I have the **2.1.1** version when I develop the site in my developer server, instead of 2.1.3.

So, I put an investigate, and Apparently the hosting guys installed a newer version of Magento on the production server. I do not know if it was 2.1.3, but it was definitely not 2.1.1. So, when I upload my site to production, I had code of 2.1.1 and 2.1.3 scrambled, and that obviously caused conflicts.

I deleted everything, and re-upload all my 2.1.1 site again, and the site is now visible. What a silly mistake. In normal situations, if someone is presented with this error, I think the joni's solution would be correct.

Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try This to clear cache and generation files

```
sudo rm -rf var/cache/* var/di/* var/generation/*
```